# C3 js, how to access json data received in url call

Tags: javascript, json, c3.js

Below is the code to generate barchart using C3 js library

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#barchart',
    data: {
      url: './API/get_bar_chart_data.php',
      mimeType: 'json',
      type: 'bar',
      keys: {
             x: 'category', // it's possible to specify 'x' when category axis
             value: [ 'number']
            },
      onclick: function (d, i) { 

                              console.log(chart.categories()[d.index]); 

                              onclick_barchart();
                              }
      },
  bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.5 // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
               }
       },    
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category' // this needed to load string x value
        }
    }

});
```

In the above code I am getting data from URL in json format.

Now on click I want to pass this complete json received to onclick_barchart() function.

Comment: Where do you get the data?  Is it d? Is that the data received? Recommend you to go through the documentation. Once you fetch it, just pass the data as an argument to the click function.

Comment: I don't know where data is received, d is some internal variable which gives index,category of the plotted chart

Comment: **I don't know where data is received**, happy coding!! That's why I told you to see the documentation. Did you?

Comment: Yes I saw the documentation, but there's no details regarding that, here's the link http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-onclick

Answer (score 0):

C3.js converts data received in internal format, so there's no way to get data as received.

IMO, there're 2 ways to handle this.

- If you need to handle data keeping as received, maybe you need to call separately. Not in context of C3.js.

```js
// call api and assign the result in separate variable
var data = call_ajax("./API/get_bar_chart_data.php");
var chart = c3.generate({
      data: {
        columns: data
        onclick: function() {
          onclick_barchart(data);
        }
      },
      ...
    }
```

- Or, access transformed data via internal data variable
  In this case, you need to handle the format as your necessity.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
      data: {
        columns: data
        onclick: function() {
          // You can access in outside via 'chart.internal.data.targets'
          // They're same result from .data() API
          // https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Chart.html#data
          onclick_barchart(this.data.targets);
        }
      },
      ...
    }
```